# Is it possible to check if my wireless network works 100%

Tags: wireless, games, bumblebee, steam

The last few days it seems like my wireless network (on the laptop) has a sort of latency. Seems like it disconnect for a second or 2 and then connect again. I dont get a notification on it, but it just seems like that.

Example: Steam -> CS:S

Refresh server-list the servers got a normal ping (40-90) and two refreshes later allmost 1500 (!!!) for then to be normal again. And I can play in a game with a latency on 60 for then the next sec 300 and then 60 again. Strange.

It haven't been like this, just the last couple of days.. I also have a delay in connecting to the servers sometimes.

And for those who plays, I get "Chokes" and "loss" in-game. Not much when spectating but when playing.

Is there a way to check the connection? If theres a problem with it? Its not the broadband speed.

- Ubuntu 12.10 64Bit
- Fujitsu LifeBook AH532

Running Bumblebee (with primus) just fine.. Or the last days when I start CS:S theres some messages in console that I dont understand :P

Any more info you have to tell me...

Difficult to explain, just frustrating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### mtr

- `sudo apt-get install mtr`
- `mtr --curses 8.8.8.8`

Leave mtr open for a while and you will get good statistics on packet loss.  You should only be interested in packets dropped within your network (before leaving your router/gateway).

Read up on some things that cause interference, such as electronic devices, magnets and big tanks of water.  Water is really a horrible thing to try to pass WiFi through.

Comment: Couldn't see any loss after 600 packages sent.. Ping up to 630 to the router, was higher then from the router to the web.. So, seems to be OK then. Strange..

Answer (score 0):

try to ping a server like google.com via the terminal, then you will know if there are any packages lost. If you packages lost then you need to improve your connection.

```
ping google.com
```

You can also try to ping the servers themselves if you have the address for them, just use the `ping` command.

but for gaming don't use a wireless network it's not stable enough, when gaming always use a wired connection for the best result.